# Masters to PhD Program

Tags: publications, graduate-admissions, graduate-school

If you have done well in undergrad (i.e one of the top students of the graduating class; physics and mathematics major with highest honors; with exposure to engineering) and have done a masters for 1-2 years with research experience and publications (i.e assisted professor and PhD students and have coauthored 2-3 papers), do you have a good chance of going to a top 10 physics graduate school?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Indeed! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a good chance of being *considered* for admission, but the set of schools you tag is so small and the competition so fierce that it isn't very likely to happen. There will be lots of other applicants who also have excellent records and not so many slots as to make decisions easy.

But, you have a shot at least, so apply. But broaden your search also, so that you have options. Some schools outside the top 10 or top 25 also have excellent programs.

I'm assuming you are in the US where "top ten" seems to be an obsession. There are other places as well, of course.

Comment: Generally speaking, who gets a high chance of getting admitted to these top programs? Can you provide some specific qualifications? My interests are in theory and experimental condensed matter physics.

Comment: Actually, it is someone like yourself. But not every fast runner will win a race. Just be aware of the competition and cover your bets.